# Laravel's email does not send( laravel 5.4)

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.4

Good morning, yesterday I was configuring the sending of email in laravel and I worked perfectly but today it does not work and gives me the following error:

> Connection could not be established with host smtp.gmail.com [ #0]

.env:

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
MAIL_PORT=465
MAIL_USERNAME=myemail@gmail.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=mypassword
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=ssl
```

mail.php:

```
'driver' => env('MAIL_DRIVER', 'smtp'),
'host' => env('MAIL_HOST', 'smtp.gmail.com'),
'port' => env('MAIL_PORT', 465),
    'from' => [
        'address' => env('MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS', 'myemail@gmail.com'),
        'name' => env('MAIL_FROM_NAME', 'nameemail'),
    ],
```

Comment: change port and encryption ( 587 => tls ) and test send email .

Comment: @Mohammad I did it and report this error:

stream_socket_enable_crypto(): SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages:
error:14090086:SSL routines:ssl3_get_server_certificate:certificate verify failed

Comment: Oh ye. Hosting must be enabled : function stream_socket_enable_crypto()

Comment: I work on local, where can I do that?

Comment: Does not matter. So confuse yourself .

Comment: Use phpmailer to test and debugging.

Answer (score 0):

Go to https://myaccount.google.com/lesssecureapps?pli=1
And allow remote access to your gmail account

Comment: I already have it done, yesterday it worked for me but today it has given me that mistake ...